# Rotation using quaternion class in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, matrix, rotation, quaternions

So I've been trying to rotate my object using only the functions provided by the Qt quaternion class:

Before drawing the object, I typed these code lines:

```
quaternion.setScalar(w);
   quaternion.setX(x);
   quaternion.setY(y);
   quaternion.setZ(z);
   QMatrix3x3 rot;
   quaternion=quaternion.normalized();
   
   rot=quaternion.toRotationMatrix();
```

Then I got stuck. I searched in the documentation and I found this function : `QMatrix3x3 QQuaternion::toRotationMatrix() const`

It creates a rotation matrix that corresponds to the quaternion. After getting that matrix what shall I do to perform the rotation. At first I rotated my object with quaternion but without using Qt functions. I used glMultMatrixf which multiplies the rotation matrix with the current matrix (modelview matrix).
Please, If someone can help, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you using QtWidgets or QtQuick (QML)?

Comment: Could f.ex. be used by the [Qt3D module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3dcore-qtransform.html)

Comment: @m7913d I'm using Qt Widgets

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use glMultMatrixf now since the rotation matrix is 3*3 and glMultMatrix is going to multiply the rotation matrix with the current one which the modelview matrix which is 4*4

Comment: You can use `Qt3DCore::QTransform` to transform the 3*3 rotation matrix into a 4*4 transformation matrix or just do it yourself. If you know/understand the mathematics behind those matrices, this should be quite simple. However, note that I'm not familiar with `glMultMatrix` (or gl in general).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the deprecated `glMultMatrix` function. Use shader OpenGL and [QMatrix4x4::rotate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmatrix4x4.html#rotate-2):

```cpp
class Object3D
{
public:
    QVector3D position = QVector3D(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    QQuaternion rotation = QQuaternion(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    QVector3D scale = QVector3D(1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    /* ... */
```

```cpp
void Object3D::draw(const QMatrix4x4 &projViewMatrix)
{
    bind();

    m_modelMatrix.setToIdentity();
    m_modelMatrix.translate(position);
    m_modelMatrix.rotate(rotation);
    m_modelMatrix.scale(scale);
    m_mvpMatrix = projViewMatrix * m_modelMatrix;
    m_pProgram->bind();
    m_pProgram->setUniformValue(m_uMvpMatrixLocation, m_mvpMatrix);
    /* ... */
}

void Object3D::bind()
{
    m_pProgram->bind();

    m_vertBuffers.vertPosBuffer.bind();
    m_pProgram->setAttributeBuffer(m_aPositionLocation, GL_FLOAT, 0, 3);
    m_pProgram->enableAttributeArray(m_aPositionLocation);
    /* ... */
}
```